# Creating a project with a cocktail API but a GET error keeps coming up in the console

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

**Javascript:**

```
const URL = "www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s="; 

const $strDrink = $('#strDrink'); 
const $strInstructions = $('strInstructions'); 
const $form = $('form'); 
const $input = $(`input[type="text"]`); 

$form.on('submit', drinksData)

function drinksData(event){

    event.preventDefault()

    const userInput = $input.val(); 

    $.ajax(URL + userInput).then(function(data){
        console.log("Let's find your cocktail!")
        console.log(data.drinks); 
        $strDrink.text(data.strDrink)
        $strInstructions.text(data.strInstructions)

        $('main').append(`<img src="${data.strDrinkThumb}"/>`)

    }, function(error){
        console.log('something is wrong')
        console.log(error)
    })
}

$.ajax(URL).then(function(data){
    console.log("Let's find your cocktail!"); 
    console.log(data); 
}, function(error){
    console.log('something is wrong')
    console.log(error)
});
```

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.min.js" integrity="sha256-hwg4gsxgFZhOsEEamdOYGBf13FyQuiTwlAQgxVSNgt4=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script defer src="./js/script.js"></script>
    <link defer href="./css/style.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <title>Cocktail Application</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Alcoholic Beverage</h1>

    <main>
        <h3>Drink Name</h3>
        <p id="strDrink"></p>
        <p>Instructions</p>
        <p id="strInstructions"></p>
    </main>
    
<form>
    <input type="text" placeholder="Drink Name"/>
    <input type="submit" value="Get Drink info"/>
</form>
    
</body>
</html>
```

Error says: jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4
GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s= 404 (Not Found)

Please help :) I'm currently trying to use the cocktail DB API to create a project website. After writing the HTML and javascript I've come across a GET problem that I can't figure out how to solve.

Comment: validate your endpoint url: path and params.

Comment: Try adding https:// to the URL

Answer (score 0):

replace `www.thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita`
with
`https://thecocktaildb.com/api/json/v1/1/search.php?s=margarita`